# read text file and show text line in random

Tags: c, file-io

I want a code to read a text file that is include some question and then select one of the questions in random and show for user till all of the question shows;

For example question:

How old are you?

Where are you from?

Now, this is my code but i don't Know to continue.

```
int main()
{
   int i = 0, line = 5;
   char ch[1000];
   char *str;
   time_t t;

    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    FILE *myfile;
    myfile = fopen("question.txt","r");
    if (myfile== NULL)
    {
    printf("can not open file \n");
    return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(ch,1000, myfile)!=NULL)
        printf("%s",ch);

    fclose(myfile);
    line = 5;
    int counter;

    for( i = 0 ; i < line ; i++ ) {
        counter = rand() % 6;
      printf("first question: %s\n", ch[counter]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

How can i to continue?

Answer (score 0):

I'd read the enitire file into a contiguous block of memory, then count the number of lines in the file (in memory) , then make an array of pointers - one pointer to each line and  change all the `'\n'`s to `'\0``s .

Finally I'd pick pointers from the array in a random order (using a basic shuffle algorithm) and display the question pointed to to the user.

if the list of questions is too big to fit in memory, the user will probably fall asleep before answering them all so, I'm assuming that won't happen.